# shopping cart empty after redirect magento 1.9

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I have installed magento community 1.9, with de default theme (rwd). The checkout on the detail page works fine, but the checkout on de category page does not work. The button redirects to an empty shopping cart. I did not customize any thing yet.